# python cache dictionary - counting number of hits

Tags: python, caching, dictionary, count

I'm implementing a caching service in python. I'm using a simple dictionary so far. What I'd like to do is to count number of hits (number of times when a stored value was retrieved by the key). Python builtin dict has no such possibility (as far as I know). I searched through 'python dictionary count' and found `Counter` (also on stackoverflow), but this doesn't satisfy my requirements I guess. I don't need to count what already exists. I need to increment something that come from the outside. And I think that storing another dictionary with hits counting only is not the best data structure I can get :)

Do you have any ideas how to do it efficiently?

Comment: Having another dictionary with hits *is* a great solution (although you have to synchronize it with original dict). Gives you lots of control and very little overhead (since you want to access these hits anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having another dictionary to store the hit counts is probably not a bad option, but you could also do something like:

```
class CacheService(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.data[key] = [item, 0]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = self.data[key]
        value[1] += 1
        return value[0]

    def getcount(self, key):
        return self.data[key][1]
```

You can use it something like this:

```
>>> cs = CacheService()
>>> cs[1] = 'one'
>>> cs[2] = 'two'
>>> print cs.getcount(1)
0
>>> cs[1]
'one'
>>> print cs.getcount(1)
1
```

Answer (score 6):

For an alternative method, if you're using Python 3 (or are willing to add [this module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245/) to your Python 2 project, which has a slightly different interface), I strongly recommend the `lru_cache` decorator.

See the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). For example, this code :

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def meth(a, b):
    print("Taking some time", a, b)
    return a + b

print(meth(2, 3))
print(meth(2, 4))
print(meth(2, 3))
```

...will output :

```
Taking some time 2 3
5
Taking some time 2 4
6
5   <--- Notice that this function result is cached
```

As per the documentation, you can get the number of hits and misses with `meth.cache_info()`, and clear the cache with `meth.cache_clear()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass a built-in `dict` class:

```
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hits = {}
        super(CustomDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.hits:
            self.hits[key] = 0
        self.hits[key] += 1
        return super(CustomDict, self).__getitem__(key)
```

usage:

```
>>> d = CustomDict()
>>> d["test"] = "test"
>>> d["test"]
'test'
>>> d["test"]
'test'
>>> d.hits["test"]
2
```

Comment: Hm, I could get the same result if I had just two dictionaries (and the same memory usage). Many people say it's not a good design to subclass built-in classes. Anyway, this solves the problem, so +1 from me

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz It's the first time I've ever heard that. There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier to just overload the built-in dict data type. This will solve your problem.

```
def CountDict(dict):
    count = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        CountDict.count[key] = CountDict.count.get(key, 0) + 1
        return super(CountDict, self).__getitem__(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return super(CountDict, self).__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def get_count(self, key):
        return CountDict.count.get(key, 0)
```

This will give you lot more flexibility. Like you can have two counts one for number of reads and another for number of writes, if you wish without much of a complexity. To learn more about super, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Edited to meet OP's need of keeping a count for reading a key. The output can be obtained by calling get_count method.

```
>>>my_dict = CountDict()
>>>my_dict["a"] = 1
>>>my_dict["a"]
>>>1
>>>my_dict["a"]
>>>1
>>>my_dict.get_count("a")
>>>2
```

Comment: OP wants a counter per key.

Comment: Thanks @freakish . I overlooked. Updated the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach.

```
class AccessCounter(object):
'''A class that contains a value and implements an access counter.
The counter increments each time the value is changed.'''

def __init__(self, val):
    super(AccessCounter, self).__setattr__('counter', 0)
    super(AccessCounter, self).__setattr__('value', val)

def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == 'value':
        super(AccessCounter, self).__setattr__('counter', self.counter + 1)
    # Make this unconditional.
    # If you want to prevent other attributes to be set, raise AttributeError(name)
    super(AccessCounter, self).__setattr__(name, value)

def __delattr__(self, name):
    if name == 'value':
        super(AccessCounter, self).__setattr__('counter', self.counter + 1)
    super(AccessCounter, self).__delattr__(name)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as such, since that is about counting the number of dictionary accesses, not attribute accesses.